# powerbuilder datawindow printing fails with no error

Tags: printing, powerbuilder

snippet here

```
ll_rtn = PrintDataWindow (ll_pjob, dw_doc)
if ll_rtn <> 1 then
    is_errortxt = "Print Failure"
    ls_rtnval = "F"
end if
```

### window behaviour

This code is executed in a window that shows customers ready for invoicing in a list. It is run dozens of times in rapid succession with a different datawindow that is loaded on the fly and generated for printing. It normally just produces a stream of print, one for each customer. Occasionally for no obvious reason it decides to not print or does not print all copies, and the error trap is not fired.

### Evidence

There is evidence that the code was executed because it is part of an invoicing run that updates a database. Updates but no prints.
The data missing from print is not the first in the list, or last or any obvious pattern.

What the users see is forty updates and thirty five or so print outs.

If you run the program to exclusively show the missing prints and run them, they print out fine.

I can't find any other instances of this on the web or any clue as to what is happening.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this 32 bit code running in 64 bit OS? Is this printing to a network printer?
 I have seen lots of problems with splwow64 and remote printing. I attempt to print to network printer several times until I succeed. Can you try: compiling application for 64 bits or printing to a local printer or try to print several times? If printdatawindow fails, printcancel and printclose the print job and printopen a new print job. Also, check the return from PrintOpen.

Comment: Have you checked the return code of the PrintOpen and PrintClose functions? I'm sure you used the first one as you have an argument for the print job number. Also, opening print jobs and not closing them can cause problems w/ hung print jobs as mentioned in the PowerBuilder help file.